# CreateNode not working IE9

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

I'm getting an error in this code on IE 9.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Create Node test</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var styleEl = document.createElement('style');
        var css = "body {};";

        if (styleEl.styleSheet){
          styleEl.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
          styleEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }

        head.appendChild(styleEl);
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It works fine in Chrome.

Thanks

P.S.
To be clear: 
I want to know why this is not working, I do not want a fix. I am trying to track down an error in IE 9 which I believe may be related to the createNode method and style elements.
Has anyone had this problem before or is it a known error in IE9?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
createNode.html, line 19 character 4

Comment: I would recommend using jQuery because it manages the inconsistency between browsers in the native javascript API's

Comment: I don't have that option unfortunately

Comment: Remove `;` should be `var css = "body {}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create Node test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var styleEl = document.createElement('style');
    var css = "body {background-color:red;};";

    styleEl.innerHTML = css;

    head.appendChild(styleEl);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: taking a fast look isn't always good :)
Place your script tag between head section instead of body.
Like my example

Comment: that shouldn't make any difference

Comment: yikes, I just realised i was in compatibility mode! Problem solved. I guesss you get the credit :-D